# Retrieving cookie

Tags: java, servlets

I'm new to servlets and I have a question about cookies.

I have a servlet where I create a cookie and write a page where I put a link to another servlet where I want to retrieve the cookie.

For some reason I can't retrieve it.  Any suggestions why it's empty?

Thx

First servlet:

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        // create new cookies
        Cookie FirstCookie = new Cookie("user", "This is the value of my first Cookie");
        //all pages on the server should receive the cookie
        FirstCookie.setPath("/");
        FirstCookie.setVersion(0);
        FirstCookie.setSecure(false);
        //60 sec * 60 min * 24h * 5d = 
        FirstCookie.setMaxAge(432000);
        FirstCookie.setComment("some comment");
        // save the cookies
        response.addCookie(FirstCookie);


    out.println("<html><body>");
    out.println("<h1>CookieServlet</h1>");
    out.println("<a href='ReadCookiesServlet'>To the Cookie page</a>");
    out.println("</body></html>");
    out.close();
}
```

Second servlet:

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("Text/html");

    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    pw.println("<html><body>");
    pw.println("<h1>Bestaande cookies:</h1>");
    Cookie[] myCookies = request.getCookies();
    if (myCookies != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myCookies.length; i++) {
            pw.println("<table border=1 ALIGN=\'CENTER\'>");
            Cookie currentCookie = myCookies[i];
            if (currentCookie.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("user")) {

                pw.println("<tr><td>" + "Name : " + currentCookie.getName() + "<td></tr>");
                pw.println("<tr><td>" + "Path : " + currentCookie.getPath() + "<td></tr>");
                pw.println("<tr><td>" + "Version : " + currentCookie.getVersion() + "<td></tr>");
                pw.println("<tr><td>" + "Secure : " + currentCookie.getSecure() + "<td></tr>");
                pw.println("<tr><td>" + "Age : " + currentCookie.getMaxAge() + "<td></tr>");
                pw.println("<tr><td>" + "Value : " + currentCookie.getValue() + "<td></tr>");
                pw.println("<tr><td>" + "Comment : " + currentCookie.getComment() + "<td></tr>");
                pw.println("</table>");
            }
        }

    }

    pw.println("</body></html>");

    pw.close();
}
```

Comment: If it is one and the same web app you can use a session to preserve state between requests. And even different web apps can share sessions. Just to be clear that this really is what you wish to do.

Comment: Are both servlets in the same web app? Otherwise, you should set the domain.

Comment: need more info.  does the first servlet set the "user" cookie?  do you see it reach the browser and is it set? (use chrome it will be easy to check).  If it does reach it, if you stop with debugger do you see the cookie sent to the second servlet?  This kind of problems are easy to debug using a debugger, so assuming you did some work to find out what's wrong please share what you've found...

Comment: Works on my machine! :) You have to provide a user parameter when you surf to the first servlet. So `http://localhost:8080/ServletExamples/CookieServlet?user=flup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is empty because it did not get set by the first servlet. The way it is currently written, you have to supply a user parameter like this: `FirstServletThatSetsCookie?user=flup` when you surf to the first servlet or it will not set the cookie at all!

Note this bit:

```
String[] user = request.getParameterValues("user");
if (user != null) {
    // create new cookies
```

Comment: I don't understand why ... the cookie itself is created (as a cookie) so the data can be extracted from there?  Or do I see it wrong?

Comment: `String[] user = request.getParameterValues("user"); if (user != null) { // set the cookie }`

Comment: I can use this when I give the Cookie as a parameter throught to the next servlet, true ... .  But the cookie has beens saved to the client, then I would think that I can retrieve it from there and I don't need to send it through as a parameter.  What use is it then to save it ... ?

Comment: I am quoting *your* first servlet's code. It is not setting the cookie, unless you send it a parameter named `user`. So while the question is "Retrieving cookie" the answer is: you're not setting it yet.

Comment: @DarthBlueRay he is telling you the truth. In your first server you are setting cookie inside `if` block and only when you send request to this server with `user` param as `http://tour_url_to_first_servlet?user` optionaly with `=some_value` at the end. If not cookie is never created because condition in `if` block is false

Comment: @flup I'm just not following you.  If I add the cookie I do write it to the client or am I wrong?  If it's there I can retrieve it from there?  I just don't see why I need to send it as a parameter to the next servlet when I would be able to retrieve it from the client.

Comment: @flup I changed the code and now the cookie is generated in the second servlets but the comment and the age e.g. is not set ... ??

Comment: @emka86  I changed the code and now the cookie is generated in the second servlets but the comment and the age e.g. is not set ... ??